# Bootbox - how to dynamically add a button?

Tags: javascript, alert, bootbox

Once a user submits a form, an alert message should pop up and say "This might take up to a minute..."

Then, once the backend job is finished, the message text should change to 'Done' and an 'OK' button should be displayed.

I can create a dialog with a button, but I'm not sure how can I add it dynamically?

```
dialog = bootbox.alert({
        title: 'This might take up to a minute, please wait.',
        message: '<p><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Submitting...</p>',
        centerVertical: true,
        backdrop: true,
        size: 'large',
        callback: function() {

        }
    }

)
```

How can I implement it? Do I need to create a new dialog or rewrite the existing one?

[Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/)

Comment: Since you've created a reference to the Bootbox dialog, you can access the "content" of the modal using something like `dialog.find('.bootbox-body')` - what you do beyond that depends on how you've configured what I assume is an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an example based on your code](https://jsfiddle.net/nsfa73b0/), which uses a timeout to mimic an AJAX call:

```js
$(function(){
    let dialog = bootbox.alert({
      title: 'This might take up to a minute, please wait.',
      message: '<p><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Submitting...</p>',
      centerVertical: true,
      size: 'large',
      closeButton: false,
      buttons: {
        ok: {
          className: 'btn-primary disabled'
        }
      },
      callback: function() {

      }
    });

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        dialog.find('.bootbox-body').html('<p>Done!</p>');
        dialog.find('.bootbox-accept').removeClass('disabled');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Assuming you're using the bootbox.alert helper and not a custom dialog, the OK button has the class `.bootbox-accept`, which we can use as a target. All content assigned to the `message` option is placed in a div with the `.bootbox-body` class, which, again, we can target.

This is the same process, for the most part, as the .init() example: http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#custom-dialog-init

If you want to automatically dismiss the dialog when your background process is done, the [overlay example](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#custom-dialog-as-overlay) pretty much does just that:

```
let timeout = 3000; // 3 seconds
let dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    message: '<p class="text-center mb-0">Please wait while we do something...</p>',
    closeButton: false
});

setTimeout(function () {
    dialog.modal('hide');
}, timeout);
```